# How to toggle button color with className in react?

Tags: reactjs, toggle

I am trying to toggle a button with hook, classname and id but all buttons toggle color instead of one button that is actually clicked.
The classname is to toggle classname "dark" and null, where .dark changes the button black.

```
import './Clothing.css'
import data from '../../data/data2.json';

const Clothing = () => {

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(null);


  const types = [
    { id: 11, value: 'All' },
    { id: 22, value: 'Cap' },
    { id: 33, value: 'Sweatshirt' },
    { id: 44, value: 'Hoodie' },
    { id: 55, value: 'Shirt' }
  ]

  const handleToggle = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id)
    if (types.filter(
      (item) => item.id === e.target.id
    )) return setToggle(!toggle)
  }

        <div className="buttonDiv">
            {
              types.map((t) =>
                <button
                  key={t.id}
                  id={t.id}
                  value={t.value}
                  className={ toggle ? "dark" : null}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    handleSelectedCategory(e);
                    handleToggle(e);
                  }}>
                  {t.value}
                </button>
              )
            }
          </div>


.clothSection {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 2rem;

    .topMenu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 2rem 4rem;

        .buttonDiv {
            gap: 2rem;
            display: flex;
            padding: 2rem 0;

            button {
                background-color: var(--InputColor);
                padding: .5rem 1rem;
                border-radius: .5rem;
                font-size: var(--NormalFontSize);
                color: var(--TextColor);
                cursor: pointer;
                border: none;
            }

            .dark {
                background-color: var(--BlackColor);
                color: var(--WhiteColor);
            }
```

Comment: can you show your css file please ?

Comment: yes sure, I just posted scss code above

Comment: Why do you `css` extension if you want to use style like `scss` ?

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: Do not add duplicate text in your question just to meet content requirements to post. It simply defeats the purpose of those requirements. Instead, add something meaningful to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you have several buttons. You wish to click a button and have that button dynamically add the `.dark` class, giving each button its own independent state.

The issue is that you have `toggle` and `setToggle` happening in a parent component. Then you render all of your buttons with the current value of `toggle`. We want each button to contain its own `toggle` value.

### New `ClothingItem.js`

I added a new component `ClothingItem.js`, which is responsible for rendering a single clothing item. Notice how this component tracks and sets its own `toggle` value, utilizing most of the code you had in place to render a button initially.

```js
const ClothingItem = ({ myKey, id, value }) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button
      key={myKey}
      id={id}
      value={value}
      className={toggle ? "dark" : null}
      onClick={() => {
        // handleSelectedCategory(e);
        setToggle(!toggle);
      }}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};
```

#### Updated `Clothing.js`

We removed all the existing state and the `handleToggle()` function. In addition, instead of rendering `<button>`s, we now render `<ClothingItem />`s, passing in `key`, `id`, and `value` as before.

```js
  return (
    <div className="buttonDiv">
      {types.map((t) => (
        <ClothingItem key={t.id} id={t.id} value={t.value} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it's working now :D life saver!

Answer (score -1):

Hello you should use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) like this:

```
classNames({ dark: toggle })
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply but it still doesn't work :(